# R Shiny: Get reactive text without div or span, just "plain" text

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display some reactive text, depending on selections the user made in my shiny UI. And then I want to display this text in normal HTML manner like:

```
h2(textOutput("PageTitle"),
          style="color: #01519E; margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;"),
```

If I use inline=TRUE on the text Output it doesn't help either since it creates a span out of it. But I just really want the "plain" text without any other HTML markups added by shiny. Is that even possible?

Comment: Why not use `uiOutput` and return the whole `h2`?

Answer (score 0):

Later answer, but here is the solution: You have to pass the style in the div around.

```
div(
  h2(
    textOutput("PageTitle")
  ),
  style="color: #01519E; margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;"
)
```